# How to display the hierarchical data

Tags: controls, hierarchy, library, info-visualisation, javascript

Some real ui javascript library wanted!

I have to display some hierarchical data on the web page. It should **not** be a classical tree view **with the text items**. I am looking for a graphical implementation and it should have minimal interactivity: I want to see current item and its parent and all children, then I click on parent(or child item) and after animation I will see this item (parent, children)

This library is exists, but I cannot find it.

[image: Here is it]

Comment: Your description is quite abstract. I think we could help you better if you posted a mockup of how you want this to look.

Comment: @Rahul I have added image

Comment: This question (although already answered) belongs on StackOverflow, not here.

Comment: @Charles Boyung I was looking for a some control and something else...

Comment: If that were true, why did you just ask for a javascript library and nothing else; and why did you accept an answer that provided nothing but a technical solution?

Comment: @Charles Boyung I accepted answer that pointed me to the thing i was looking for. ;)  I know, if someone has no alternative answer, he /she should not have any objections. I have not seen any answer and any reference to an answer from you. :)

Comment: What were you asking for besides a library? I can't see anything else in your question. And since asking for a code library doesn't belong on this site, there's no reason to provide an answer to it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider [a search for "javascript visualisation library"](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+visualisation+library) on Google. Several promising results:

- John Resig's [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) - you'll probably have to write your specific visualisation yourself
- the [Javascript InfoVis toolkit](http://thejit.org/) - check the demos page for some examples of interactive tree maps, which represent hierarchies as you described in your question
- [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) - a lot of great examples here, though unfortunately none of the examples look exactly like your proposal

Hope those help. You definitely want to be using the term "information visualisation" when searching for libraries. Perhaps that will help you find the library you're thinking of.

Comment: thejit.org would be my first choice, but alas has a poor notion of 'up' vs 'down' for layered graphs.

Answer (score 4):

Something like a [Zooming User Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zooming_user_interface)? You could try [Zoomooz.js](http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/) in that case.

Comment: +1 it is a nice one! but it should be tree view. any way it will help me to build my page(s) also. thank you, Max!

Comment: Awesome library, Max! There was a question a week ago where this answer would have been terrific, but it got closed.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... this probably doesn't answer your question directly, but this might help:
[Simple and fast templating tool to generate HTML from JSON data](http://beebole.com/pure/)

Comment: I have added image.

Answer (score 2):

for minimal interaction, you could also use http://www.graphviz.org/ and generate an image, SVG, or similar output.  Alas, the 'canvas' object used by most of the javascript solutions is not printable.

Comment: Thank you for this and post link. I have question: What do you mean about "not printable"? Could you describe for more details. I cannot print a web page with control that uses the canvas? thank you.

Comment: when one tries to print a web page that contains a canvas, like 'flot' for example, the result is a blank area.  OR SO I THOUGHT!  turns out that any examples I tried to re-create resulted in a proper image.  Perhaps the whole debate on 'printable' canvas is no longer applicable or perhaps was only related to server-side image generation?  Thanks igor for asking your question!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for a library, but first things first.
Is this the UI you are desiring?

[image: hierarchy w/o a tree]

Comment: I have added image

Comment: Ah-ha, I see.  Sorry for the confusion.
Your question is a good one....